# how to fix itunes uploading app exceptions of java?

Tags: objective-c, ios

When I tried to submit my app from xcode to itunes, the following error appears:

```
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
/Users/Omars/Desktop/2480623426.itmsp - Error Messages:
                An error has occurred during the upload.
                An exception has occurred: The operation timed out.
                Transfer error.
                An exception has occurred: The transport has been detected as having failed and has been aborted.  Please try again.
                An error occurred while uploading the files to Apple's remote server.
                An error occurred while uploading the package 2480623426.itmsp.
                Apple's web service operation was not successful
                Unable to authenticate the package: 2480623426.itmsp
                ERROR ITMS-9000: "java.lang.Error: Internal error:
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by doing the following :
Note that I am using XCode 4.4.1

this terminal commands :
    cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
    sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5

for more information from apple discussions:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/18048796#18048796#18048796#18048796